# Define Variable Variable and use it in $_POST

Tags: php, variables, post

Simple questions I hope but I just can't get the solution.

I have a foreach loop producing variable `$checkbox`.

I then have a field name, for the example `approvereject`

I want to create a new variable that combines the fieldname and the forecah value.

So:

```
$joinedvariable=approvereject.$checkbox
```

This does not work, I have also tried:

```
$joinedvariable=${approvereject_.$checkbox};
```

but when I echo `$joinedvariable` I simply get a blank result.

Lastly, I want to use `$joinedvariable` in a `$_POST` statement:

`$_POST[$joinedvariable ]` - will this work as I cant get it right?

Comment: Has nothing to do with variable variables. You just need a concated array key for `$_POST` ($_POST is an array variable, not a "statement", or "function").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
$joinedvariable="approvereject".$checkbox;

$_POST[$joinedvariable];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$joinedvariable='approvereject'.$checkbox
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have some code like this:

```
foreach ($checkboxes as $checkbox) {
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="approvereject_'. $checkbox .'" value="1">';
}
```

in a `<form>` with `method="post"`, than you can try to get values of checkboxes like this:

```
foreach ($checkboxes as $checkbox) {
    print_r(!empty($_POST['approvereject_'. $checkbox]));
}
```